# How setup gradle to prefer repositories from init.gradle to build.gradle?

Tags: gradle

Pls, help understand how gradle work.

In linux server i have Java project and build them from gradle 4.10.3.

In Project i have build.gradle file with repositories section. Also in subproject i have this file too.

build.gradle example:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://1.2.3.4'}
}
subprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
          maven { url 'http://1.2.3.4'}
        }
   }
 repositories {
          maven { url 'http://8.2.3.4/'}
        }
}
```

I`m try override repositories in init.gradle file (locate in folder $GRADLE_HOME/init.d/)

But this doesnt work. When build project, gradle use repositories from build.gradle project (and subproject) file.

Also i`m try run gradle with option -I and path to init.gradle file - same result.

```
gradle -I $GRADLE_HOME/init.d/init.gradle  -Pprod clean build
```

Can i override repositories section in build.gradle (located in project and subproject) by use some file in local environment, or may be some $env or something else ?

UPD.

in init.gradle file i write this:

```
settingsEvaluated { settings ->
    settings.pluginManagement {
        resolutionStrategy {
        }
        repositories {
          maven {url 'http://13.1.1.21:8084'
           
          }

        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {url "http://10.8.13.21:8080/repository/"
            
          }
     }
  }
```

Comment: What is the value of `GRADLE_HOME`?

Comment: export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle-4.10.3/